# creating star ratings in mobile web site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any option to implement star ratings in mobile website (html,css and js based)?

html as follows

```
<div class="rating">
 <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
 </div>
```

and css as

```
.rating > span:hover:before {
content: "\2605";
position: absolute;
}
```

The star images are not showing up in my mobile browser. Is there any other way to do this without using any jQuery plugins?

Here I have given only hover functinality, also I need the stars to get checked according to their rating.

Comment: How could a touch screen have `:hover`? Just ponder that one for a while...

Comment: @FDL from a user experience point of view you are correct, but on ios atleast when a hover is applied it acts as a 'first click' event and then when hover state is active, a second click would fire the click

Comment: "The star images are not showing up in my mobile browser." - What is showing up?

Comment: i tried this way too!its also not working ! http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/CGP87/light/

Comment: CSS cannot make any permanent changes to the page. Therefore, you will need at least some JavaScript, to either change the value of a `<input name="stars">` form field that will be sent to the server, or save the number of stars locally. Thus, I'd advise you to just use [a jQuery plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+stars).

Comment: Could it be that Safari is not interpreting the `"\2605";` correctly?

Comment: try an event in evengee.com that is a site I built to learn SOLR. But it has some star-rating widget in it, although it does not work, u see the stars, and clicking it marks the stars correctly. Take that code as a starting point. Enjoy (Tested on iPhone)

Comment: Paul D. Waite:its showing up some special characters like this  ^a~

Answer (score 1):

I use this library for a star rating system on my web app.

http://wbotelhos.com/raty

It only requires jQuery, and is really easy to use.